# Create vector of appended dates in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (set1) with 3 fields - **date** (date), **price** (numeric) and **event** (logical).
I would like to create a vector that returns the **date** when **event** is TRUE.

I have been able to do this for **price**: returns a vector of 346 prices

```
n <- c()
for(i in 1:length(set1$price)){
    if(set1$event[i] == TRUE) {
      n <- append(n,set1$price[i])
  }
}
```

However, when I try to do the same for **date** only the first **date** when **event** is TRUE is returned:  2001-10-29

```
n <- c()
for(i in 1:length(set1$date)){
    if(set1$event[i] == TRUE) {
      n <- append(n,set1$date[i])
  }
}
```

I tried to assign the empty vector as a date field but the result was still the same:

```
n <- c()
n <- as.Date(as.character(n), format = "%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[` subsetting on the logical vector `event`.   For example, here's some made-up data

```
date <- seq(Sys.Date()-5, Sys.Date(), 1)
event <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
(set1 <- data.frame(date, event))
#         date event
# 1 2014-11-09 FALSE
# 2 2014-11-10  TRUE
# 3 2014-11-11  TRUE
# 4 2014-11-12 FALSE
# 5 2014-11-13 FALSE
# 6 2014-11-14  TRUE
```

Then you can subset the `date` vector by the `event` vector and all the dates for which event is TRUE will be returned.

```
with(set1, date[event])
# [1] "2014-11-10" "2014-11-11" "2014-11-14"
```

And you could do the same for the pricing column in your data.

Comment: R is beautifully vectorized :) Often times, loops are not necessary at all.

Comment: You are right. I was over complicating it. With subsetting I can have a data frame with both the date and price.